# Starting an edge from within a node

Tags: linked-list, visualization, graphviz

```
digraph foo {
a [label="<first> A | <rest> rest", shape=record];
b [label="<first> B | <rest> rest", shape=record];
a:rest -> b [label="foo", arrowtail=dot, dir=both];
}
```

I would like to start the tail of the edge (a to b) from within a:rest (ideally in the center), is this possible?

I am trying to draw linked lists using box and pointer like notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. The attribute to use is called [`tailclip`](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:tailclip):

> If true, the tail of an edge is clipped to the boundary of the tail
>   node; otherwise, the end of the edge goes to the center of the node,
>   or the center of a port, if applicable.

Just change your last line to

```
a:rest -> b [label="foo", arrowtail=dot, dir=both, tailclip=false];
```

Edit: As @Kyborek mentions in the comments, an additional compass point is needed for current versions of graphviz:

```
a:rest:c -> b [label="foo", arrowtail=dot, dir=both, tailclip=false];
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13904775/63733)

Comment: Ok, this is the instruction to achieve this and this _should_ work, but it looks like it doesn't, depending on the system and the graphviz version. It works on http://graphviz-dev.appspot.com/, but not on my local install (graphviz 2.27 and 2.28).

Comment: Yes I could not get it working as well - any idea what version that website uses?

Comment: No, I don't know which version.

Comment: This solution did not work for me too. The feature was updated, all is explained in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898151/drawing-outgoing-edges-starting-from-the-center-of-record-elements-in-graphviz in case somebody stumbles in here.