# Graphviz Linked list arrow tail origin

Tags: linked-list, graphviz

I would like to draw a vertically aligned linked list, like the one from Wikimedia Commons:

[image: Credit: wikimedia commons]

My best shot so far is:

```
digraph foo {
        rankdir=LR;
        node [shape=record];
        a [label="{ <data> 12 | <ref> }"]
        b [label="{ <data> 99 | <ref> }"];
        c [label="{ <data> 37 | <ref> }"];
        d [shape=box];
        a:ref -> b:data [arrowhead=vee, arrowtail=dot, dir=both];
        b:ref -> c:data [arrowhead=vee, arrowtail=dot, dir=both];
        c:ref -> d      [arrowhead=vee, arrowtail=dot, dir=both];
}
```

Which gives:

[image]

How do I set arrowtail dot to originate from within the record, and set the `d` record to appear as an `X` node?

I've tried `tailclip=false`, with no luck.

Comment: For part of the answer, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020529/starting-an-edge-from-within-a-node

Comment: Tried `tailclip=false`, no luck - updated my question.

Comment: Solution using TikZ rather than GraphViz (although personally I like GraphViz!): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19286/how-should-i-draw-a-singly-double-linked-list

Comment: It was the `:c` part I was missing, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to set `tailclip=false` *and* indicate a **compass point** for the tail end of the edge:

```
digraph foo {
        rankdir=LR;
        node [shape=record];
        edge [tailclip=false];
        a [label="{ <data> 12 | <ref> }"]
        b [label="{ <data> 99 | <ref> }"];
        c [label="{ <data> 37 | <ref> }"];
        d [shape=box];
        a:ref:c -> b:data [arrowhead=vee, arrowtail=dot, dir=both];
        b:ref:c -> c:data [arrowhead=vee, arrowtail=dot, dir=both];
        c:ref:c -> d      [arrowhead=vee, arrowtail=dot, dir=both];
}
```

[image: graphviz output]

Unfortunately, the shape you need for the last node is not included in the [default shapes](http://www.graphviz.org/content/node-shapes) available. You could add a [custom shape](http://www.graphviz.org/wiki/how-create-custom-shapes) using postscript or a bitmap image, or even [SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7302526/63733) if using SVG output.

Comment: I note that an X is not a standard arrow shape either. There goes that clever idea. Some authors just use the word "NULL" instead of a cross in the box for the empty node. If I had written PostScript code this decade, I would make you an EPS file that would suffice for the custom node shape.

Comment: Depending on what output you need, you may be able to make something nice looking with SVG. Otherwise, just put a huge X in a box, change the font and its size for that node... a hack, I know :(

Comment: Aha, I think it's easy and practical to create the EPS file needed for the custom node shape using a vector graphics editor such as Inkscape.